Why is bytes(lst) slower than bytearray(lst)?
With lst = [0] * 10**6 I get times like these:
  5.4 ± 0.4 ms  bytearray(lst)
  5.6 ± 0.4 ms  bytes(bytearray(lst))
 13.1 ± 0.7 ms  bytes(lst)

Python:
3.13.0 (main, Nov  9 2024, 10:04:25) [GCC 14.2.1 20240910]
namespace(name='cpython', cache_tag='cpython-313', version=sys.version_info(major=3, minor=13, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0), hexversion=51183856, _multiarch='x86_64-linux-gnu')

I would've expected bytes(lst) and bytearray(lst) to be equally fast or bytearray(lst) to be the slower one, since it's the more complicated type (has more functionality, as it's mutable). But it's the other way around. And even the detour bytes(bytearray(lst)) is much faster than bytes(lst)! Why is bytes(lst) so slow?
Benchmark script (Attempt This Online!):
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import random
import sys

setup = 'lst = [0] * 10**6'

codes = [
    'bytes(lst)',
    'bytearray(lst)',
    'bytes(bytearray(lst))'
]

times = {c: [] for c in codes}
def stats(c):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[c])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(codes)
    for c in codes:
        t = timeit(c, setup, number=10) / 10
        times[c].append(t)
for c in sorted(codes, key=stats):
    print(stats(c), c)

print('\nPython:')
print(sys.version)
print(sys.implementation)

Inspired by an answer that also found bytearray to be faster.

@MaartenBodewes The testing is fine. I do 25 rounds, randomly shuffling the three codes before each round. Then take the fastest 5 results for each code. And this is Python, doesn't need warm-up as much as I think Java does.

They use marginally different implementations. Compare bytesarray to bytes. Relevant commit. The bytes constructor has not been updated in 6 years. Feel free to open a ticket (after looking for duplicates).

@Homer512 Interesting, if that's the case you might actually just wrap bytearray to create a immutable bytes, although the wrapping would introduce overhead as well of course.

@MaartenBodewes Do you mean my bytes(bytearray(lst)), or something else?

@KellyBundy No, I meant for the Python implementors. Best is to reimplement bytes altogether, but as an intermediate they could just always use bytebuffer and forward any method calls to the underlying class, so they would have the same performance + some overhead for the additional call.

As pointed out by @Homer512 in the comments, bytearray and bytes are implemented quite differently in CPython. While bytearray was given a fast path for creation from list and tuple with GitHub issue #91149, bytes did not receive the same optimization.
The said fast path for bytearray takes advantage of the PySequence_Fast_ITEMS, which returns an array of objects, when given a list or a tuple, so that all items can be obtained by simply iterating over the array.
The creation of bytes from a list, on the other hand, has to make a PyList_GET_ITEM call to obtain each item in the list with each index, hence the comparatively low performance.
I've refactored the code for bytes creation from list and tuple in my PR #128214, which, with a benchmark using:
python -m timeit -n 100 -s 'a = [40] * 100000' 'bytes(a)'

shows a ~81% increase in performance:
100 loops, best of 5: 3.43 msec per loop # current
100 loops, best of 5: 1.89 msec per loop # PR #128214

and is indeed faster than the same benchmark constructing bytearray instead:
100 loops, best of 5: 2.14 msec per loop


Do you know why bytes becomes faster than bytearray with your PR? What's the difference between them? I'd still rather expect them to be equally fast.

This is because, while the bytes constructor allocates the needed memory block directly, the allocation of memory for a bytearray is done in the initializer as an in-place memory reallocation through resizing, which comes with the overhead of Python's memory management context. We may indeed bring bytearray to partiy with bytes by directly allocating memory for it too.
